# Flex 3 & XML Namespace

Tags: xml, flex3, xml-namespaces

I'm using Flex 3. I updated from Flash 9 to Flash 10 and from SDK 3.2 to 3.6.

I noticed that when I add an XML tag, it now asks for a namespace. In my previous set-up it didn't ask for this. What do I put as the namespace? I though that it was part of the Flex core.

```
<mx:XML xmlns="">
```

I'm having problems with Flex forcing me to escape characters for XML data. Is this problem related to the missing namespace?

Answer (score 2):

test it:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

Comment: Hi Bitetti, Thank you for your message. I'm using Flex 3 (not Flex 4), so I don't have Spark components.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore it, remove the xmlns attribute

```
<mx:XML>
```